# run sed in dockerfile to replace text with build arg value

Tags: sed, dockerfile

I'm trying to use sed to replace the text "localhost" in my nginx.conf with the IP address of my docker host (FYI. using docker machine locally, which is running docker on 192.168.99.100).

My nginx Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM nginx:alpine
ARG DOCKER_HOST
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
RUN sed -i 's/localhost/${DOCKER_HOST}/g' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
```

My nginx.conf file looks like this (note: majority removed for simplicity)

```
http {

   sendfile on;

   upstream epd {
      server localhost:8080;
   }

   # ...
}
```

I'm expecting "localhost" to get replaced with "192.168.99.100", but it actually gets replaced with "${DOCKER_HOST}". This causes an error

> host not found in upstream "${DOCKER_HOST}:8080"

I've tried a few other things, but I can't seem to get this working. I can confirm the DOCKER_HOST build arg is getting through to the Dockerfile via my docker compose script, as I can echo this out.

Many thanks for any responses...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Replace the single quotes `'` around `s/localhost/${DOCKER_HOST}/g` with double quotes `"`. Variables will not be interpolated within single quotes.

Comment: I had tried this and I got the following during the build:

    Step 4/6 : RUN sed -i "s/localhost/${DOCKER_HOST}/g" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ---> Running in 20ac4ad09c9e
    sed: bad option in substitution expression
    ERROR: Service 'reverseproxy' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c sed -i "s/localhost/${DOCKER_HOST}/g" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf' returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: Could you post the variable you are using for DOCKER_HOST? I imagine when the substitution is done there is a character that is breaking the sed expression (e.g. a slash). You may be able to fix by using another character as a separator like `|` or `;` instead of `/`.

Comment: I define the DOCKER_HOST arg in an .env file, which is used by docker-compose. In the .env file I set DOCKER_HOST=192.168.99.100. In my Dockerfile I have a run command; RUN echo "|${DOCKER_HOST}|", which correctly outputs |192.168.99.100| to the console. I should also point out I'm using docker machine from a windows host - this configures docker on a moby linux VM in virtual box.