# How to pass variable to init.sql file from docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

Tags: docker

See below code:

I want to pass a variable from Dockerfile or wherever to my init.sql file.
How can I do this?

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM postgres
ADD init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

**init.sql**

```sql
CREATE TABLE ${SOME_ARGUMENT_HERE}(
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
completed BOOLEAN NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so far I've created this

**docker-compose.yml**

```
build:
  context: .
  args:
   - PG_TABLE=${PG_TABLE}      # Comes from .env variable
```

**seed.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE ${PG_TABLE}(
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
completed BOOLEAN NOT NULL);
```

**script.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sed  -i "s/\${$1}/$2/g" dump.sql
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM postgres
ARG PG_TABLE

ADD seed.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/seed.sql

# pass variable PG_TABLE to script.sh to replace ${PG_TABLE} with .env variable in seed.sql
WORKDIR /scripts
COPY script.sh .
RUN chmod +x script.sh
RUN /scripts/script.sh PG_TABLE "${PG_TABLE}"
```

Finally fixed.
I realised the problem was because my script.sh was not targeting the destination of /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/seed.sql

Comment: You should move the run command after the add

Comment: @Nabil It's not passing the value of $PG_TABLE.  Atleast its not echoing it out

Answer (score 2):

You can use for example script or execute shell command using sed/awk to replace your variable `${SOME_ARGUMENT_HERE}` with  some other variable that has been passed to the Dockerfile

Example of command

```bash
sed  -i 's/${SOME_ARGUMENT_HERE}/TEST-REPLACE/g' init.sql
```

Example of shell script (replace.sh)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sed  -i 's/${SOME_ARGUMENT_HERE}/TEST-REPLACE/g' init.sql
```

Comment: ok thanks. I'm not familiar with bash scripts. Could you provide a basic example?

Comment: You can something like this ```sed  -i 's/${SOME_ARGUMENT_HERE}/TEST-REPLACE/g' init.sql ```

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, but how do you run that script before the copy of it to docker?

Comment: in your dockerfile. You can copy the file the run the command on the copied file. Here an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54075585/17766295)

Comment: So just curious, how do you get the .env variable inside dockerfile to script file?

Comment: The easiest option is to execute the command directly. If you want to use a bash script you can pass it as variable like [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg)

Comment: ok to stop this conversation - see above my solution from your suggestion. I am missing one final step I think.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but you can also place shell scripts in the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` folder. These get executed at the same time that `.sql` scripts would get executed. Inside the script, you have access to the environment variables, and can use them directly in a sql script that you can pass to `psql` in heredoc style:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

# Using a shell init script to be able to use environment variable substitution
psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "$POSTGRES_DB" <<-EOSQL
  CREATE TABLE ${SOME_ARGUMENT_HERE}(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
  completed BOOLEAN NOT NULL);
EOSQL
```

Then you use any means you prefer to set the `SOME_ARGUMENT_HERE` variable, for instance in your Dockerfile (`ENV SOME_ARGUMENT_HERE=fooTable`).